# How to get every available number inside of an array like somearray[evernumber]

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So this is an output object that I get. this is when you output. sampresponse.players with samp-query npm

```
[
  { id: 0, name: 'djandar', score: 127, ping: 82 },
  { id: 1, name: 'Nememuruhilebey', score: 69, ping: 98 },
  { id: 2, name: 'illuminateForces', score: 13219, ping: 108 },
  { id: 3, name: 'floridian.', score: 200, ping: 168 },
  { id: 4, name: 'afdan', score: 2583, ping: 67 },
  { id: 5, name: 'kaxni', score: 3210, ping: 93 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sahin_K', score: 415, ping: 92 },
  { id: 7, name: 'Frank1061', score: 251, ping: 77 },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alphatester', score: 4068, ping: 311 },
  { id: 9, name: 'Vyp3r', score: 1893, ping: 98 },
  { id: 10, name: 'SerbieNikLalbanie', score: 1, ping: 70 },
  { id: 11, name: 'skkkrt', score: 880, ping: 114 },
  { id: 12, name: 'SikikM4', score: 0, ping: 99 },
  { id: 14, name: 'metowill', score: 1398, ping: 88 },
  { id: 16, name: 'Bob_Alonzo', score: 206, ping: 96 },
  { id: 18, name: 'dzandar', score: 54, ping: 81 },
  { id: 20, name: 'Clay', score: 0, ping: 515 },
  { id: 22, name: 'Sabitto', score: 568, ping: 114 },
  { id: 23, name: 'Leidys', score: 3832, ping: 97 },
  { id: 25, name: 'killergod', score: 4688, ping: 95 },
  { id: 26, name: '.dose', score: 11058, ping: 86 },
  { id: 27, name: 'Trail', score: 4024, ping: 70 },
  { id: 28, name: 'Lil_Alperr', score: 6784, ping: 80 },
  { id: 31, name: 'Aliisthebest', score: 3, ping: 301 },
  { id: 32, name: 'memurbeey', score: 150, ping: 96 },
  { id: 33, name: 'Sagem', score: 5294, ping: 45 },
  { id: 35, name: 'KoBi1', score: 3156, ping: 133 },
  { id: 36, name: 'realturkoncel', score: 10460, ping: 86 }
]
```

The number of lines depends on how many players are online on the samp server. using samp-query npm
So I need my output to be like this.
For example, this would be first line. as id 0.

```
0 djandar 127 82
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
sampresponse.players[0].name
```

but that only shows the name in the first line I need it to show all names.
I also tried this.

```
sampresponse.players.name
```

But that comes as undefined.
I have one idea but I don't know how to execute it.
So when you go like this

```
sampresponse.players.length
```

the out put is 36 as the number of last id.
So my idea is to loop throw all number from 0 to the number output by sampresponse.players.length which is the last number. Something like this 0 - sampresponse.players.length
But I don't know how to loop throw all the numbers and show all the names, scores and pings, so I was hoping some of you can help me.

Comment: `sampresponse.players.map(x => x.name)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: sampresponse.players.map(x => x.name) This displays all the names but is there a way to remove , and display one name per line something like this 
name1 (ID) - score - ping new line
name2 (ID) - score - ping
and like that for all the players.

Comment: Yes, just remap to whatever you want. It's the same idea again - you get each item in the `map` callback and you can extract any property you want, produce any string you want and finally you'd get a new array based on the transformation defined in `map`. So if you do `sampresponse.players.map(x => x.name + " " + x.id)` You'd get the name and ID separated by a space. Or you can do whatever format suits you.

Comment: Yeah, that worked that I got format that I wanted. Thanks. One last thing I don't know is how to get one player per line. Now they are just one by one separated by , Is there a way to get then one player per line.

Comment: I got a new line with \n  and the only thing left is that I don't know is how to remove ,

Comment: You have an array. If you need the items separated by a newline, then just do `arr.join("\n")`

Comment: Thanks for all the help I got it working like this. first i difined that map as player list  then playerlist.toString().replace(/,/g, "")  with that i removed the , and new line with /n,

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the array:

```
const data = [
  { id: 0, name: 'djandar', score: 127, ping: 82 },
  { id: 1, name: 'Nememuruhilebey', score: 69, ping: 98 },
  { id: 2, name: 'illuminateForces', score: 13219, ping: 108 },
  { id: 3, name: 'floridian.', score: 200, ping: 168 },
  { id: 4, name: 'afdan', score: 2583, ping: 67 },
  { id: 5, name: 'kaxni', score: 3210, ping: 93 },
  { id: 6, name: 'Sahin_K', score: 415, ping: 92 },
  { id: 7, name: 'Frank1061', score: 251, ping: 77 },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alphatester', score: 4068, ping: 311 },
  { id: 9, name: 'Vyp3r', score: 1893, ping: 98 },
  { id: 10, name: 'SerbieNikLalbanie', score: 1, ping: 70 },
  { id: 11, name: 'skkkrt', score: 880, ping: 114 },
  { id: 12, name: 'SikikM4', score: 0, ping: 99 },
  { id: 14, name: 'metowill', score: 1398, ping: 88 },
  { id: 16, name: 'Bob_Alonzo', score: 206, ping: 96 },
  { id: 18, name: 'dzandar', score: 54, ping: 81 },
  { id: 20, name: 'Clay', score: 0, ping: 515 },
  { id: 22, name: 'Sabitto', score: 568, ping: 114 },
  { id: 23, name: 'Leidys', score: 3832, ping: 97 },
  { id: 25, name: 'killergod', score: 4688, ping: 95 },
  { id: 26, name: '.dose', score: 11058, ping: 86 },
  { id: 27, name: 'Trail', score: 4024, ping: 70 },
  { id: 28, name: 'Lil_Alperr', score: 6784, ping: 80 },
  { id: 31, name: 'Aliisthebest', score: 3, ping: 301 },
  { id: 32, name: 'memurbeey', score: 150, ping: 96 },
  { id: 33, name: 'Sagem', score: 5294, ping: 45 },
  { id: 35, name: 'KoBi1', score: 3156, ping: 133 },
  { id: 36, name: 'realturkoncel', score: 10460, ping: 86 }
]

data.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.id, item.name, item.score, item.ping);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to transform the values of an array.

```
sampresponse.players.map(player => [
  player.id,
  player.name,
  player.score,
  player.ping
]);
```

This will result in an output looking like this:

```
[
  [0, "djandar", 127, 82],
  [1, "Nememuruhilebey", 69, 89],
  ... //all the other players
];
```

Is this the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just remap to whatever you want. It's the same idea again - you get each item in the map callback and you can extract any property you want, produce any string you want and finally you'd get a new array based on the transformation defined in map. So if you do sampresponse.players.map(x => x.name + " " + x.id) You'd get the name and ID separated by a space. Or you can do whatever format suits you. – VLAZ

That solved my problem thanks for all your help.